# Distance and displacement of an object on a straight line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, distance, displacement

I had this homework problem, but don't actually know if what I did is right, or that I even read the problem correctly. Can someone please tell me if this is the right interpretation of the problem and my answer is right or wrong?

> 1. at $t=0s$ an object has a position of $-4.0m$ and without changing direction moves to a position of $+6.0m$ at $t=4.0s$ It then moves in a straight line and accomplishes a displacement of $-8.0m$ at the $t=8.0s$ mark. For the $8.0s$ interval:
>
>    a. What was the total distance the object traveled?
>    b. What was the objects overall displacement?
>    c. What has been the object's average speed?
>    d. What has been the objects average velocity?
>    e. At $t=8.0s$, what is the object position?

So what I did is this:

*a.* I did $6-(-4)-(-8)$ and got a total distance of $22m$

*b.* It says the displacement of $-8.0$m

*c.* Average speed would be $\frac{22m}{8.0s}=2.75m/s$

*d.* Average velocity would be $\frac{-8.0m}{8.0s} = -1.0m/s$

*e.* Would it be $-12.0m$?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange, Link! I completely forgot until now to let you know that "check my work" questions are not really encouraged on this site, and that's why your question got closed. If you have a particular reason to believe that something you did might be wrong, e.g. an answer doesn't make sense, or there is a concept that you're not sure how to apply, then make the question about that, and it can be a great question. See our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) and [FAQ#questions] for more information.

Comment: Okay then, thanks, I didn't know, I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the object was traveling on x-axis, hence we have following 
$(@t = 0,\ x = -4);\ (@t = 4,\ x = 6);\ (@t = 8,\ x = 6-8 = -2)$ Hence we have

$a)\ \  {{|(6 - (-4))| + |(-2 - 6)|}} = 18. $

$b)\ \ {-2 - (-4)} = 2. $

$c)\ \  {18\over8}.$

$d)\ \ {2\over8}.$

$e)\ \ -2.$

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, thanks, never thought of it that way.

Comment: quartz, our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) specifies that we shouldn't post complete answers to homework-like questions like this. Normally I would temporarily delete this, but since it has already been read and accepted I'll leave it alone. Just keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: Yea, this is fine, but I would have liked pointers, but nice job, especially like the sentence about the x-axis, once i got that, everything else was cake.