# Does differentiating a distance with respect to time give velocity?

Tags: velocity, differentiation, speed, distance, displacement

I'm just wondering if you have a distance function:
$$ 
s(t) = 0.1t^2 - 5t 
$$
where $s(t)$ is distance and $t$ is time in seconds, does differentiating it give you a function for velocity?

Comment: Suggestion to the post (v5): Replace [the word _distance_ with the word  _displacement_](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-1/Distance-and-Displacement). See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317197/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: What is your definition of "velocity" if not doing exactly that?

Answer (score 1):

*Distance* is a scalar quantity. Differentiating *distance* with respect to time gives *speed*. *Speed* is also a scalar quantity. While *velocity* is a vector quantity, and *velocity* is the differentiation of *displacement* with respect to time. *Displacement* is a vector quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. The average velocity over a period $\Delta t$ is given by
$$
v = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t} 
$$
The (instantaneous) velocity is the average velocity upon an infinitesimal interval of time
$$
v = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t} = \frac{ds}{dt}
$$
The latter equality follows immediately from the definition of a derivative.